# Make <h1> vertically center with CSS?

Tags: css, html

```html
<header id="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" />
    <h1>Some text here</h1>
</header>
```

I use

```
h1{display: inline;}
```

to make them in the same line, but the text is lower than the image,
the images is 48x48px and the text size is 23px, I'd like to make the text vetically center to the image, how could I do that with CSS? Just need to support Chrome.

Thanks for your answers, finally got it work: http://jsfiddle.net/tFdpW/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xs4x6/

```
<header id="logo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/48x48/f0f/fff" />
    <h1>Some text here</h1>
</header>

header img {
    vertical-align: top
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 48px
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what rules of rendering/layout mandate your solution? Also, it seems that solution without hardcoding image size in css should be possible and clearly better – do you know one?

Comment: A slightly different way that makes more sense: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xs4x6/363/

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `vertical-align:middle;` to the image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Uxs7w/

Comment: You can play with CSS, e.g. add `margin:0 8px 8px 0;` to the img.

Answer (score 3):

```
h1{display: inline;line-height:48px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

@wong2; first of all. `inline` property doesn't support vertical margin, padding properties .So, there are other options.

first: remove `display:inline` & give `float` to it.

```
img, h1{float:left;}
h1{margintop:15px; margin-left:10px;}
```

second: give `display:table` to it.

```
#logo{display:table}
img, h1{display:table-cell}
h1{vertical-align:middle;}
```

thrid: if don't want to remove `display:inline`.

```
h1{display: inline;line-height:48px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the "logo" header got the right height, just use the css `vertical-align:middle` property

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: I set header's height to 50px, then set h1's vertical-align to middle, not working..

Comment: you must assign it to the image

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
h1 {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```